# Combining two lists and printing all the values corresponding to a certain value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I need to combine two lists and then count all the values corresponding to a certain value.

The two lists are:

```
inControl = ["False", "False", "True", "True","False", "True", "False", "True", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False"]

rts = [379, 396, 480, 443, 365, 280, 487, 446, 350, 367, 405, 391, 484, 359, 367, 305, 359, 479, 436, 333]
```

I need to sum all of the `rts` corresponding to all of the `False` values, and then the same for `True` values (they are all in order).

I've basically got as far as combining the two lists using as a `zip` function, but am completely lost as to what to do next... any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks:)

Comment: Look into `itertools` and specifically into `groupby`. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: @TammoHeeren: for `groupby`: "Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function". Would need to sort the tuples here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good comment. You are absolutely correct. Should be sorted on `inControl` here.

Comment: In that case, just find first index of "True" and perform 2 sums on 2 sublists. But the sort operation takes time.

Comment: Use `sum` with a generator: `sum(e for e, c in zip(rts, inControl) if c=='False')`

Comment: `sumtrue = sum(rt for rt, ic in zip(rts, inControl) if ic);sumfalse = sum(rts) - sumtrue`

Answer (score 2):

Seems weird that the booleans are strings, but...

Use `zip`, then `sum` on matching elements.

(re-create the `zip` for the other part in Python 3 because `zip` is an iterable)

```
inControl = ["False", "False", "True", "True","False", "True", "False", "True", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False"]

rts = [379, 396, 480, 443, 365, 280, 487, 446, 350, 367, 405, 391, 484, 359, 367, 305, 359, 479, 436, 333]

z=zip(rts,inControl)
sf=sum(x[0] for x in z if x[1]=='False')
z=zip(rts,inControl)
st=sum(x[0] for x in z if x[1]=='True')
print(sf,st)
```

result:

```
5128 2783
```

Maybe `st` could be computed with less string comparisons with `sum`: `st=sum(rts)-sf` (more additions, less string comparisons)

**variant:** small loop for True & False

```
s=dict()

for c in ['False','True']:
    z=zip(rts,inControl)
    s[c]=sum(x[0] for x in z if x[1]==c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Jean-François's solution will work just fine and is pretty readable. It does make two passes over the data, though. If the list is small this isn't a big deal, but if it's big you can roughly halve the time of operation by taking a single pass.

One general approach is this:

```
totals = {}
for flag, value in zip(inControl, rts):
    totals[flag] = totals.setdefault(flag, 0) + value
```

This code does not assume that `inControl` has only `False` and `True`. It can in fact have any number of unique values.

A cuter way is to use the `Counter` class from the `collections` module. A `Counter` is a dictionary intended to keep track of counts. Adding two counters does the obvious thing: the values of identical keys are summed. We can create a `Counter` instance for each pair of elements and add up all of the counters. Note that creating a `Counter` for each element is probably overkill -- the above solution is more efficient. But for educational purposes, this solution looks like:

```
from collections import Counter
counters = (Counter({k: v}) for k, v in zip(inControl, rts))
sum(counters, Counter())
```

Comment: Your first solution is very efficient. How can do a little more by initialize `totals = {'True': 0, 'False': 0}`. That way, you don't have to call `setdefault` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can produce tuples that have a single number either in the `False` position or `True` position in a list comprehension or generator exrpession:

```
>>> [(e,0) if c=='False' else (0,e) for e, c in zip(rts, inControl)]
[(379, 0), (396, 0), (0, 480), (0, 443), (365, 0), (0, 280), (487, 0), (0, 446), (0, 350), (367, 0), (405, 0), (391, 0), (484, 0), (359, 0), (367, 0), (0, 305), (359, 0), (0, 479), (436, 0), (333, 0)]
```

You can then sum series of tuples with `reduce`:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), (((e,0) if c=='False' else (0,e) for e, c in zip(rts, inControl))))
(5128, 2783)
```

You can actually use `False` and `True` booleans to access the tuple:

```
>>> t=reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), ((e if c=='False' else 0, e if c=='True' else 0) for e, c in zip(rts, inControl)))
>>> t[False]
5128
>>> t[True]
2783
```

Or, you can use `map` if that makes more sense to you:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*((e,0) if c=='False' else (0,e) for e, c in zip(rts, inControl))))
[5128, 2783]
```

Or, you can create a dict with the sums:

```
>>> dict(zip([False, True], map(sum, zip(*[(e,0) if c=='False' else (0,e) for e, c in zip(rts, inControl)]))))
{False: 5128, True: 2783}
```

If you have Pandas, a great way to do this is with `.groupby()` and `sum`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'rts':rts, 'inControl':inControl})
>>> df
   inControl  rts
0      False  379
1      False  396
2       True  480
3       True  443
4      False  365
5       True  280
6      False  487
7       True  446
8       True  350
9      False  367
10     False  405
11     False  391
12     False  484
13     False  359
14     False  367
15      True  305
16     False  359
17      True  479
18     False  436
19     False  333
>>> df.groupby(inControl).sum()
        rts
False  5128
True   2783
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
inControl = ["False", "False", "True", "True","False", "True", "False", "True", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "True", "False", "False"]
rts = [379, 396, 480, 443, 365, 280, 487, 446, 350, 367, 405, 391, 484, 359, 367, 305, 359, 479, 436, 333]
```

I assume that `inControl` is a list of strings, not a list of booleans. For my solution to work, I am going to convert `inControl` to list of booleans:

```
inControl = [element == 'True' for element in inControl]  # ==> [False, False, ...]
```

Use `itertools.compress` to calculate sum of all `True` elements:

```
import itertools
true_sum = sum(itertools.compress(rts, inControl))  # 2783
```

Now, we can calculate the `false_sum`:

```
grand_sum = sum(rts)              # 7911
false_sum = grand_sum - true_sum  # 5128
```